# unsigned char in javascript

Tags: javascript, c, node.js

Converting this code to javascript:

```
for( i = 0; i < 256; i++ )
    m[i] = (unsigned char) i;
```

How do I convert the `unsigned char` part?

```
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  m[i] = (?)i
}
```

Comment: `m[i] = i` ? There is only "number" in in JS as numerical data type. Rather thinking about how to convert that code exactly, you should find out why `m[i] = (unsigned char) i;` is done in the first place and then decide whether it's applicable to JS.

Comment: This is part of an arc4 prng . I'll try to check here why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do anything at all to the value to get the corresponding result:

```
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  m[i] = i;
}
```

An `unsigned char` in C is an 8 bit integer data type that can hold the values 0 to 255. As no value in the loop goes outside that range the cast doesn't change any of the values, it only changes the data type to fit the type of the array.

As numbers in Javascript are double precision floating point numbers, you will naturally not get an array of 8-bit values. Whether that is an issue is a matter of how the array is used later on.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I'm not really good with C.

As for the `how the array is used` does this help? [link to my other related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337316/arc4-prng-c-to-javascript-code)

Comment: @majidarif: Values are only moved around in the array, so that won't be a problem.

Comment: great. Thank you. Learned something today :)

Comment: If `m` is a _Uint8Array_ then it will be stored as an 8-bit int, unless bits/bytes/memory footprints are really important it's not usually worth it over _Array_.

Comment: @PaulS. I didn't get that.

Comment: @majidarif: In newer browsers (e.g. IE 10+) you can also used typed arrays. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Comment: @majidarif: Right, then you don't have cross browser issues. You just have to check if the Javascript version you are using supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

To calculate the unsigned char value, try:

```
m[i] = i % 256;
```

As Guffa said, an unsigned char in C is an 8-bit integer data type that can hold the values 0 to 255. So, in JS, we do not have a specific datatype. You can make a custom function like this:

```
export function toSigned (input) {
 return input % 256;   }
```